# DisplayFormatAttribute not recognized in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Following a ASP.NET core MVC [video](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses-embed/introduction-to-aspnet-core-10-16841/Video-Creating-a-Form-eYlqdeE6C_1006218965%22) from Microsoft, and coding it myself as well.

I got in a strange situation where code entering isn't recognized. Not sure why, might I miss some using statement, or is something else wrong.

All code is based upon the standard default ASP Web application, when creating a new ASP.NET Core web application (not an empty ASP.NET Core project) so providing a model should not depend on other files as it's quite a common thing I believe, and this should be the place where all views depends on to properly format the date notation (which in europe is day-month-year and not the default in ASP.net core).

I have a Movie.cs in the Models folder and it looks like below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
      public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

    // The [Displayformat(... verb is not recognized and got a red line under it

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}",ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]  
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use [tag:asp.net-core-mvc] tag instead. [tag:asp.net-mvc] is for the old legacy ASP.NET MVC stack. Also there is no MVC6, its called ASP.NET Core MVC for almost a year

Answer (score 1):

The attribute class `DisplayFormatAttribute` lives in namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.

So you should add this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Comment: i just found it, but your earlier posting it, intellisence did as well notice it but l looked over it